# Angular CLI executable (ng) always show only the list of available commands

Tags: angular-cli

Windows
@angular/cli@13.1.2
node -v 16.13.1
npm -v 8.1.2

```
ng [command]
```

in windows CMD always give the list of available commands, like in case of just

```
ng
```

but if I use VSCODE console it works fine

Comment: PLease be more specific in your question. What do you expect to happen, what happens 1. with ng and a command in the VSCODE console, 2. in the normal console, 3. with just ng in the VSCODE console, 4. in the normal console.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the NPM cache didn't work for me but running `npm run ng [command]` worked as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the terminal. The issue is being on CMD.
Try bash or vscode_terminal or install a preferred one.

Answer (score -1):

Solved. The problem was in the node version and npm cache.

Comment: I am facing the same issue can u please explain what fix you made

Comment: I took Node version that is noted in doc for angular + cleared npm cache