# why running angular command always show the list of command available

Tags: angular

Similar to this question [Angular CLI executable (ng) always show only the list of available commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70385390/angular-cli-executable-ng-always-show-only-the-list-of-available-commands)

I am facing the same issue. whenever I run any angular command in windows CMD it will always shows the list of command available instead of executing the command

in this example I run ng --version in windows terminal and powershell.

[CMD Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLpQa.png)

but it works in powershell

[Powershell screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RUU8.png)

Comment: What happens in cmd of you run ng — —version?

Answer (score -1):

The correct command is `ng version` in order to check the version of Angular CLI

https://angular.io/cli/version